# Extract data between tags in shell script and store in array?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using a `bash` script to obtain a value from a URL and it's returning a value in *html tags* form.  Input:

```
<tr><td title='The name of the health check service.'>hc.name</td><td data-type='java.lang.String'>Replication Queue</td></tr>
<tr><td title='The persistence identifier of the service.'>service.pid</td><td data-type='java.lang.String'>com.adobe.granite.replication.hc.impl.ReplicationQueueHealthCheck</td></tr>
<tr><td title='The health check result'>ok</td><td data-type='java.lang.Boolean'>true</td></tr>
<tr><td title='The health check status'>status</td><td data-type='java.lang.String'>OK</td></tr>
<tr><td title='The elapsed time in miliseconds'>elapsedTime</td><td data-type='java.lang.Long'>18</td></tr>
<tr><td title='The date when the execution finished'>finishedAt</td><td data-type='java.util.Date'>2017-03-24T00:23:36+0530</td></tr>
<tr><td title='Indicates of the execution timed out'>timedOut</td><td data-type='java.lang.Boolean'>false</td></tr>
```

The desired output should be stored in a variable with the values between `<td>` tags from the above code:

```
values=( ["hc.name"]="Replication Queue" ["status"]="OK")
```

I tried to use this `sed` code, but it only works when multiple `<td></td>` tags are on separate lines. In this case, multiple `<td></td>` are on the same line.

```
sed -n 's:.*<td>(.*)</td>.*:\1:p' sample.txt
```

That command displays results only with input like this:

```
<tr>
<td>ok</td>
<td>status</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I'm new to Shell scripting and I tried few commands using sed/awk, but it's not working and I also don't know how to populate it as array structure mentioned above.

Comment: Is there any shell script/command you used? please describe the problem and tell what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: sed -n 's:.*<td>\(.*\)</td>.*:\1:p' sample.txt

This command I tried to use but it works when multiple <td></td> tags are in separate lines. But, in my case, multiple <td></td> are in same line.

Comment: The usual answer here is "don't use regexes to parse HTML". A best-practices approach would be more like using `xmltidy` to convert your HTML to XML, and then XMLStarlet to parse that XML to text.

Comment: ...regex-based approaches are fragile, because there are lots of ways HTML can change how it's written and still remain semantically identical. A real HTML parser will also know to change `&amp;` to `&` and do similar transformations where needed, which any regex-based tool will miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have better luck using Perl regular expressions for this, since they support non-greedy matching. Here is a Perl one-liner that prints the information from your file:

```
perl -ne 'm:.*?<td [^>]*>(.*?)</td>.*?<td [^>]*>(.*?)</td>:; print "[\"$1\"] = \"$2\"\n";' sample.txt
```

This outputs:

```
["hc.name"] = "Replication Queue"
["service.pid"] = "com.adobe.granite.replication.hc.impl.ReplicationQueueHealthCheck"
["ok"] = "true"
["status"] = "OK"
["elapsedTime"] = "18"
["finishedAt"] = "2017-03-24T00:23:36+0530"
["timedOut"] = "false"
```

Here is a sed invocation that also works, but this is less precise as it matches all characters except `>` and `<` to approximate non-greedy matching, which is not supported in sed.

```
sed -n 's:.*<td [^>]*>\([^<]*\)</td><td [^>]*>\([^<]*\)</td>.*:[\"\1\"] = \"\2\":p' sample.txt
```

This outputs:

```
["hc.name"] = "Replication Queue"
["service.pid"] = "com.adobe.granite.replication.hc.impl.ReplicationQueueHealthCheck"
["ok"] = "true"
["status"] = "OK"
["elapsedTime"] = "18"
["finishedAt"] = "2017-03-24T00:23:36+0530"
["timedOut"] = "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

`sgrep` and `sed` method (more reliable than pure `sed`):

```
sgrep -o'%r"' '">" __ "<"' sample.txt | sed 's/^/["/;s/""/"/;s/"/"]="/2'
```

Output:

```
["hc.name"]="Replication Queue"
["service.pid"]="com.adobe.granite.replication.hc.impl.ReplicationQueueHealthCheck"
["ok"]="true"
["status"]="OK"
["elapsedTime"]="18"
["finishedAt"]="2017-03-24T00:23:36+0530"
["timedOut"]="false"
```